# JS- Popup Work in all browsers BUT Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, popupwindow

I have 1 problem:
I try authorization in Google/Gmail in Popup.

THis is my JavaScript code:

```
var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
var SCOPE = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/';
var VALIDURL = 'https://www.localhost:1987/Home/GetContacts?code=';
var CLIENTID = 'MyClientId';
var REDIRECT = 'http://localhost:1987/Home/GetContacts'
var TYPE = 'code';
var _url = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;

function login() {
    var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');

    var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {

        try {
            console.log(win.document.URL);
            if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                console.log("NOW THIS WINDOW WLL BE CLOSE!");
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url = win.document.URL;
                acToken = gup(url, 'code');                    
                win.close();

                validateToken(acToken);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }, 100);
}
function validateToken(token) {
    console.log("Text before my ajax");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetContacts?code=' + token,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

        data: {},

        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var info = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#ContactsList').empty();

            for (var i = 0, len = info.length; i < len; i++) {
                console.log(info[i].ContactMail.ContactMail);
                var contact = $('<div/>');
                contact.text(info[i].ContactMail);
                contact.text(info[i].ContactName);
                $('#ContactsList').append(contact);
            }

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(xhr);
        }
    })
}

//credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
function gup(url, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[[]/, "\[").replace(/[]]/, "\]");
    var regexS = "[\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(url);
    console.log(results);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}

function Test()
{
    var win = window.open("http://www.google.com", "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');
    win.close();
}
```

This is my simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>GoogleContacts</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
    <script src="~/Scripts/ImportContacts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <a href='#' onclick='login();'> click here to login </a><br/>
        <a href='#' onclick='Test();'> IE Test</a>
        <div id="ContactsList">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In 2 browser(Chrome,Firefox) it working nice.
But in Internet Exploler I get next error:
TypeError: Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference

In both link(second just for fast checking)

Comment: Likely a security issue since the URL in the window is not from same origien as the page that opens and interrogates the window

Comment: @mplungjan  So how i can resvole it??
BTW- here is example and he working good
http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/04/authentication-and-authorization-for-google-apis-in-javascript-popup-window-tutorial.html

Comment: Please fr sure change  `<a href='#' onClick='login();'> click here to login </a>` to  `<a href='#' onClick='login(); return false'> click here to login </a>`

Comment: thnak you for answer but its didnt work too((